# Comparing Values Using Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large table of data that I am hoping to summarize/check using a pivot table. A simplified version of my original table:

```
ID         X1   X2    X3    01.14   02.14   03.14...
ab1         a    b     1      2       3        4
ab2         a    b     2      2       3        4
abTotal     a    b   Total    4       6        8
ac1         a    c     1      2       3        4
ac2         a    c     2      2       3        4
acTotal     a    c   Total    4       6        8
aTotal1     a  Total   1      4       6        8
aTotal2     a  Total   2      4       6        8
aTotalTotal a  Total Total    8       12       16
    :
```

I would like to me check if my numbers match in each period -- ie. is aTotalTotal the sum of ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2 and is it the sum of abTotal and acTotal, etc.

I am trying to use a pivot table but right now everything gets summed together.

Comment: It seems like you have subtotals turned on. If you could turn-off the sub-totals, then it would be possible for you to pick up ab1, ab2, ac1, ac2, aTotal1, aTotal2 and sum them up and compare against aTotalTotal. Check out this link on how to turn off the sub totals - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-subtotals-and-totals-in-a-pivottable-fc4d8406-f230-4762-aa2f-310826f3e5e2

Comment: Looking at your question, I just now realised that this is your original table, not the PivotTable, so my above method doesn't hold good. You could use filters in your PivotTable to exclude the rows that you do not want to be picked, but then you need to identify the rules on how to exclude abTotal and acTotal.

Comment: @BharatAnand if I used filters, I wouldn't be able to compare the -Total fields with their component parts. I was hoping that I would be able to almost specify a sumif for the grand total line?